# Can we get rid of position measurements in order to measure momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

It seems from many examples that momentum measurements inevitably involve position measurements. For example, if I want to measure the momentum of a charged particle, I pass it through a magnetic field and infer the curvature and hence momentum from the position measurements made by detectors placed around the region of magnetic field.

So assuming the truth of the following statement(at least for some cases) "The experimental setup for momentum measurements also measure position",

how do I find a consistency with the following two theoretical postulates/results

- When an observable is measured on a system, the systems wavefunction jumps to an eigenstate of the observable that is measured
- Position and momentum don't have common eigenstates.

Answer (score 0):

The position of the measuring device and the momentum of that which is measured can have a common eigenstate.

Comment: i.e when we entangle the 'apparatus' with the system, and make position measurement on the apparatus to infer momentum of system,  the apparatus jumps to a position eigenket and the system jumps to a momentum eigenket???

Comment: But there are momentum measurement, where we don't use your suggested method, like in measuring the momentum of a charged particle by measuring its position using detectors surrounding the magnetic field through which the charged particles are passed. So, I guess the question remains.